# How to change text color in a Button?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I was wondering if it is possible to change the color of the text in Antd. For instance, I'd like this button to have the color of the text black`#000000` and the icon `DownloadOutlined` in purple `#5e46a1`

**My code**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
      <Button type="primary">
        <DownloadOutlined/>
        My Button
      </Button>
  );
};
```

Have not been able to find the correct CSS attributes to inject in style inside `DownloadOutlined`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Button>
      <DownloadOutlined style={{color:"purple"}}/>
      <span style={{ color: "black" }}>My Button</span>
    </Button>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html code would become:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
      <Button type="primary" className="custom_btn">
        <DownloadOutlined className="custom_btn_icon"/>
        My Button
      </Button>
  );
};
```

and your css code would be:

```
.custom_btn {
  color: #00000 !important; 
}
.custom_btn_icon {
  color: #5e46a1 !important; 
}
```

Don't forget to use `!important` to override default antd's styling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
      <Button type="primary" style={{color: "black"}}>
        <DownloadOutlined style={{color: "purple"}} />
        My Button
      </Button>
  );
};
```